# Why is my session property not displaying across all pages in ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, model-view-controller, ejs

I am a beginner to node.js and am learning about sessions. I have a login button that routes to a post request called /login and in that request I am attempting to create a new session using a userprofile object. This userprofile object is hardcoded now with set properties. I then set this object to the session and render to the views. I want the views to grab the property of username of this userprofile object stored in the session. I have a condition to check if theUser was rendered in the view. If the session is not created, the placeholder user is sent correctly but if the session is created, username will be displayed. If I navigate to a different page, the session object is considered undefined again and I don't know why, the user placeholder pops up again and username disappears, even though the session still exists. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
router.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  if(!req.session.theUser) {
    var newUser = new theUser('0', 'bob', 'jones', 'bob@gmail.com', 'address', 'US');
    req.session.theUser = newUser;
    res.render('login', {theUser: req.session.theUser});
    console.log(req.session.theUser.userFname);
  } else {
    res.render('savedLibraries' );
  }
});
```

```html
<%if(typeof theUser != 'undefined') { %>
  <li><a><%= theUser.username %></a></li>
<%}else if(typeof theUser == 'undefined'){ %>
  <li><a>User</a></li>
<%}%>
```

Comment: I can see one reason why the username is not visible when a session is created. `<li><a<%= theUser.username %>></a></li>` should be `<li><a><%= theUser.username %></a></li>`. Note the placement of the `>`

Comment: Wow thanks, don't know how I didn't see that. My main problem still stands, the username is not visible on other pages even though the session still exists. It goes right back to being undefined and the placeholder is displayed the second I navigate away from the page.

Comment: your EJS code is a bit odd: may I recommend `if (typeof theUser !== "undefined") { ... } else { ... }` instead. Note the `!==`, not `!=`, and also note that we don't need another if: something that isn't a, is not a. The end.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, but it keeps reverting back to the placeholder instead of the username when I navigate to another page. The second I post to login, it updated appropriately but when I navigate it reverts to the placeholder. The session still exists perfectly fine though, and I can destroy the session as intended. No idea why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer I found was to send the session object to every single view.